# Convert XML to CSV not working

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

XML file Content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<servstate>
<title>2018-06-11  12:00:01</title>
<services>
<service>
<name>Oracle Weblogic AdminServer 1</name>
<state>RUNNING.</state>
</service>
<service>
<name>Oracle WebLogic NodeManager 1</name>
<state>RUNNING.</state>
</service>
<service>
<name>OracleProcessManager_1</name>
<state>RUNNING.</state>
</service>
<service>
<name>OracleProcessManager_2</name>
<state>RUNNING.</state>
</service>
<service>
<name>Oracle WebLogic NodeManager 2</name>
<state>RUNNING.</state>
</service>
<service>
<name>Oracle Weblogic AdminServer 2</name>
<state>RUNNING.</state>
</service>
</services>
</servstate>
```

I am new to PowerShell and written a script to parse the above XML as CSV file but I got the result as below.

Script:

```bsh
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\monitoring_services.xml)
$xml.servstate.services.service |
    Select-Object @(@{l="name";e={$_.name."#text"}}, @{l="state";e={$_.state."#text"}}) |
    Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

```
"name","state"
,
,
,
,
,
,
```

Expected result:

```
"name","state"
Oracle Weblogic AdminServer 1,RUNNING.
Oracle WebLogic NodeManager 1,RUNNING.
OracleProcessManager_1,RUNNING.
OracleProcessManager_2,RUNNING.
Oracle WebLogic NodeManager 2,RUNNING.
Oracle Weblogic AdminServer 1,RUNNING.
```

Could you help correct what went wrong the script?

Comment: `@{l="name"...` should be: `@{n="name"...`

Comment: @iRon - Tried but same result ..

Comment: @iRon L for label or n for name are both valid. But that's not he point see RobinSidharth's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just use this?

```
$xml.servstate.services.service | Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you complicating things? Why don't you just select the Name and the State and export it to CSV:

```
$xml.servstate.services.service | Select-Object Name, State | Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You don't need to create custom properties if you already have something that you need.

Comment: Since at that level there are only name and state the select isn't neccessary, and your answer differs in nothing from @RobinSidharth answer.